# Qt QCombobox currentIndexChanged signal

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, qcombobox

How get ItemIndex from one ComboBox and send to another ComboBox? Both Comb's created in QTableWidget

```
QComboBox *comboA = static_cast<QComboBox*>(ui->tableWidget->cellWidget(0,0));
QComboBox *comboB = static_cast<QComboBox*>(ui->tableWidget->cellWidget(0,1));
QObject::connect(comboA, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)),comboB, SLOT(setCurrentIndex(int)));
```

But this code does not work. Rather, it is necessary to define new methods for pointers.

Comment: Please define "does not work", and use dynamic_cast or qobject_cast for those casts and check for null pointer, also make sure that you run connect right after you create the combo-boxes, before you expect them to change simultaneously, also check the Creator's application output for connection errors.

Comment: Thanx for comment. I forgot to define my slot in header file.