# QT - How to get SIGNAL "currentIndexChanged" from QVector<QComboBox*>

Tags: c++, qt

I want to get QString text from selected QComboBox. When I selected an index on a QComboBox, I want to get QString from the selected index, after I clicked the desired index on a QcomboBox.

I have researched about this,

1. [Qt QCombobox currentIndexChanged signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748109/qt-qcombobox-currentindexchanged-signal)

but have not found a way to solve it,

```
QVector<QComboBox*> cboxes;
 for (int i =0; i< 40 ; i++)
{
QComboBox *box = new QComboBox();
cboxes.append(box);
}
    for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
    {
        connect(cboxes[i], SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(const QString &text)), this, SLOT(comboBoxAdjusted_Changed(QString)));
    }
```

comboBoxAdjusted_Changed function

```
void DialogSettings::comboBoxAdjusted_Changed(QString text)
{
    std::cout << text.toStdString() << endl;
}
```

I have Try, but everytime i change the combobox index, It isn't give output.

```
for (int i =0; i< 40 ; i++)
    {
    connect(cboxes[i], static_cast<void(QComboBox::*)(const QString &)>(&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged),
                        [=](const QString &text){
                        std::cout << text.toStdString() << endl;
    });
```

What should I do?

Comment: What is the problem? What do you want to get ?, also please show comboBoxAdjusted_Changed

Comment: QSignalMapper might be what you want, as a wild guess...

Comment: @eyllanesc i have edit my question.

Comment: What do you want to do in comboBoxAdjusted_Changed?

Comment: @eyllanesc I want to write to tcpSocket.

Comment: Do you want to get the current text of the selected combobox or all combobox ?, please improve your description, it is unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see signal syntax is missing the function input argument.

Below are two valid signals for `currentIndexChanged`

```
void    currentIndexChanged(int index)
void    currentIndexChanged(const QString &text)
```

If you have to handle `index` try below for your case.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
 {
     connect(cboxes[i], static_cast<void(QComboBox::*)(int)>(&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged),[=](int index){ /* YOUR CODE */ });
 }
```

Comment: Okay, I will try it

Comment: Or `qOverload<int>(&QComboBox::currentIndex)`, much clearer. (Or `QOverload<int>::of(&QComboBox::currentIndex)` on older versions).